# Not equal operator in a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What would be the correct syntax to set the following user condition to NOT equal?

```
@instance = Comment.all(:joins => :user, :conditions => { :users => { :status => 'unpaid' } })
```

In other words, I am trying to accomplish something like this, but obviously the syntax doesn't work.

```
@instance = Comment.all(:joins => :user, :conditions => { :users => { :status != 'unpaid' } })
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: I am not 100% certain but would `...{ users[:status] != 'unpaid'}...` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Comment.joins(:user).where("users.status != 'unpaid' or users.status is null")
```

In this case you will get all users who has status unpaid or doesn't any status. This query generate sql as bellow:

```
SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" INNER JOIN "users" ON "comments"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE ("user.status != 'unpaid' or user.status is null")
```

Comment: Hi, this is a good solution... but if you could explain the changes you made and why they work - that would help future newbies who find this solution when they google for their own problems :) Don't forget that what is obvious to you or me, might not be obvious to a newbie - and lots of them arrive at S/O via google... and they could learn from your experience :)

Comment: Not sure what else more to write. If you can , please add more explanation . Thanks

Comment: I'd explain how I changed from using the old "all"+hash" syntax to using the arel version of `.join` and `.where` and why this change is good. As well as pointing out that to use != you need to pass it as a sql string instead of using the default hash-syntax... plus I'd explain why it's necessary to add the "is null" part of the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this

```
Comment.joins(:user).where("status != ? or status is null",'unpaid')
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write a small snippet of SQL to make that work. Try this:

```
Comment.joins(:user).where("users.status != 'unpaid'")
```

Which generates:

```
>  Comment.joins(:user).where("users.status != 'unpaid'").to_sql
SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "comments"."user_id" WHERE (users.status != 'unpaid')
```

To include results with nil or empty status:

```
Comment.joins(:user).where("users.status != 'unpaid'").where("user.status" => "").where("user.status" => nil)
```

Comment: Hi Dave.  This seems to return only one record.  But, I'd also like to return the other records that are blank or nil for this "status" attribute.  Any thoughts?